# How to get a `onPress` callback with data in `TouchableOpacity`

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to handle a tap on a row of items in `ListView` using `TouchableOpacity.onPress`, but everything I try fails in a slightly different way.

I have `renderRow` function, provided to `ListView.renderRow`. In here I want to do:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress= { () => this.tapRow(rowData) }>
        <View style={{margin: 5, backgroundColor: "#EEE" }}>
            <Text>{rowData.text}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

And my `tapRow` function is:

```
tapRow(rowData) {
    console.log( "Tapped Row: " + rowData.id )
}
```

This results in the error `_this3.tapRow is not a function ... _this3.tapRow is undefined`.

Looking at references I've also tried adding `this.tapRow = this.tapRow.bind(this)` to the constructor, but that doesn't help.

For a test I've also done `onPress={this.tapRow}`. This doesn't cause an error, but the function is never called (I do a simple console.log in it to verify)

How do I get a function called in `onPress` and provide arguments to it?

Comment: try to do this on tapRow, tapRow = (rowData) => {
   console.log("TEST");   
}

Comment: @GaneshCauda That's something I tried, and tried again now. Same problem of `_this3.tapRow` being undefined.

Comment: ah and the onpress, try to do this, onPress= { () => this.tapRow({rowData}) }

Comment: You need to `bind()` `renderRow`  too. Or for simplicity, just use arrow functions.

Comment: @Dan thanks. That was the missing bit.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `renderRow` function on constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this)
}
```